# Error uploading LaTeX file to arXiv

Tags: errors

I am trying to upload my LaTeX file on arXiv for submission. Unfortunately, I am getting this error.

```
Transcript written on research.log.

[verbose]: pdflatex 'research.tex' failed.
[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'research.aux' (1599046895 >= 1599046895)
[verbose]: 'htex' is not a valid TeX format; will ignore.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running htex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2016/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/3350246/ && tex 'research.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=tex)
(./research.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
[]{article}
?
! Emergency stop.
l.1 \documentclass
[]{article}
No pages of output.
Transcript written on research.log.

[verbose]: tex 'research.tex' failed.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running tex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2016/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/3350246/ && tex 'research.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=tex)
(./research.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
[]{article}
?
! Emergency stop.
l.1 \documentclass
[]{article}
No pages of output.
Transcript written on research.log.

[verbose]: tex 'research.tex' failed.
[verbose]: We failed utterly to process the TeX file 'research.tex'
[error]: Unable to sucessfully process tex files.
*** AutoTeX ABORTING ***

[verbose]: AutoTeX returned error: Unable to sucessfully process tex files.

[verbose]: $autotex->process failed $@: $?: 0 $!: Inappropriate ioctl for device
[verbose]: Error running AutoTeX process:
```

The preamble of my LaTeX looks like this:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\date{}
\usepackage{cite}
\pdfoutput=1
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[total={6.5in, 8in}]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}

\usepackage{abstract}

\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\title{}

\author[1,*]{Devanshu Shekhar}
\author[2]{Satyananda Panda}

\affil[1]{Department of Physics, National Institute of Technology Calicut, Kerala, India}
\affil[2]{Department of Mathematics, National Institute of Technology Calicut, Kerala, India}
\affil[*]{Corresponding author: Devanshu Shekhar, devanshu2096@gmail.com}

\begin{document}
```

I can't find a way out!

Comment: For the most part they are all listed in the logfile.

Comment: Actually I need these files to upload with my LaTeX file to arXiv for building. I don't know how to get those from logfile.

Comment: They are listed with the full path name, e.g., `fontspec` is (on my machine, with my details removed): `c:/.../texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty`. Knowing where the file is, it can then be copied into your bundle. When you say "get those [files] from logfile", do you mean you want a script to copy the files automatically? But which ones? Doesn't arxiv already have the standard ones? (TexLive 2016, it looks like). How many files are you expecting to bundle? Do you know which ones? One, or a few, files can be done manually.

Comment: Since we don't know your article contents we have no idea what you have uploaded. For arxiv it is always a good idea to never rely on very new stuff (as they are using a TeXLive from 2016). For example do you need the `abstract` package or the `blindtext` package. Make sure to only use package that you actually need. You should probably also follow the arxiv naming guidelines. Aren't there a rule about what the main article file should be named?

Comment: Thanks! I added .sty files for abstract and other packages which I needed. In addition, I removed the unwanted packages, so it worked!